# Scrapy Attribute error: type object has no attribute get

Tags: python, types, scrapy

I have been working on a scrapy script that works when running it in the shell, but when I setup to run it from python I get this error. (Error is first, code is second).

It's weird to me that it will run in the scrapy shell. Is there an error with the scrapy package? I am looking at where it says cls_path=settings.get('SPIDER_LOADER_CLASS')

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\awb71\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Rent Smart\Building Scrapers\website Scrapers\aptscom\aptscom\spiders\buildingScraper.py", line 58, in <module>
    process = CrawlerProcess(listBuildings)
  File "C:\Users\awb71\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Rent Smart\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 280, in __init__
    super().__init__(settings)
  File "C:\Users\awb71\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Rent Smart\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 152, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = self._get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "C:\Users\awb71\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\Rent Smart\env\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 134, in _get_spider_loader
    cls_path = settings.get('SPIDER_LOADER_CLASS')
AttributeError: type object 'listBuildings' has no attribute 'get'
```

Code:

```
 import scrapy 
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    
    import datetime as dt
    
    
    
    from aptscom.items import buildingsItem
    
    
    class listBuildings(scrapy.Spider):
    
        name='buildinglist'
        start_urls=['https://www.apartments.com/new-york/']
        page_number=2
    
    
        custom_settings =  {"FEEDS":{"buildings.json":{"format":"json"}}}
    
        
        def parse (self, response):
            item = buildingsItem()
          
            print(response.css('li.mortar-wrapper'))
    
    
            for building in response.css('li.mortar-wrapper'):
    
                item['Building'] =  building.css('span.js-placardTitle::text').get()
    
    
                yield item
    
    
    process = CrawlerProcess(listBuildings)
    process.crawl()
    process.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the settings, change:

```py
process = CrawlerProcess(listBuildings)
process.crawl()
process.start()
```

to

```py
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl('buildinglist')
process.start()
```

Read [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).