# Unable to run scrapy from other python file passing urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to start scrapy after having done a few other things in my main. After having parse some data I have the URLS and want to pass them first to scrapy and then start the process.

main

```
        urls = {'start_urls': ['google.com']}

        spider = LiveSpider(None, **urls)
        #spider.run()
        process = CrawlerProcess(LiveSpider)
        process.crawl(spider)
        process.start()
```

scrapy implementation

```
class LiveSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'live'
    allowed_domains = ['google.com']
    #start_urls = []

    def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LiveSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.start_urls = kwargs.get('start_urls')
        for url in self.start_urls:
            print('urls: ' + url)
        print('Urls done')

    def parse(self, response):
        res = response.text
```

Log

```
urls: google.com
Urls done
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jocke/PycharmProjects/theca-crawler/read_sitemap.py", line 95, in <module>
    process = CrawlerProcess(LiveSpider)
  File "/home/jocke/PycharmProjects/theca-crawler/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 289, in __init__
    super().__init__(settings)
  File "/home/jocke/PycharmProjects/theca-crawler/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = self._get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/home/jocke/PycharmProjects/theca-crawler/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 148, in _get_spider_loader
    cls_path = settings.get('SPIDER_LOADER_CLASS')
AttributeError: type object 'LiveSpider' has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: hope this answer your question,   https://stackoverflow.com/a/70737972/18060154

Answer (score 0):

After running a few more tests this is the solution. Add start_urls to the call to crawl.

No need for having **init** function at all

Main

```
#Define urls list before
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(LiveSpider, start_urls=product_urls)
process.start(stop_after_crawl=False)
```

Scrapy impl.

class LiveSpider(scrapy.Spider):

```
name = 'live'
allowed_domains = ['google.com']
start_urls = []

def parse(self, response):
    res = response.text
    #Do some parsing
```